# Restangular: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I'm trying to play with angularjs and restangular.
I have problems using restangular as it give me an error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
        at Object.login (localhost:8000/src/common/factories/session.js:110:38)
        at localhost:8000/src/common/factories/session.js:207:34
        at Scope.$emit (localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.js:12809:33)
        at Scope.$scope.Login (localhost:8000/src/common/factories/session.js:185:28)
        at localhost8000/vendor/angular/angular.js:10735:21
        at localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.js:18942:17
        at Scope.$eval (localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.js:12595:28)
        at Scope.$apply (localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.js:12693:23)
        at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
        at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

(localhost:8000/vendor/angular/angular.js:18941:21)

My controller is here : https://github.com/Seraf/LISA-WEB-Frontend/blob/master/src/common/factories/session.js#L188 and calling the login function (line and pos in the error above)

Here, it seems it doesn't play well with Restangular as I have the error pasted above.
As I'm new to angularjs, maybe I don't do the best practices ... I already inject restangular as dependency on my root module : https://github.com/Seraf/LISA-WEB-Frontend/blob/master/src/app/app.js#L6 maybe it causes some problems ?

**[EDIT]**
Guilty lines are :

110: ".setBaseUrl('backend/api/v1')"

207: "$Session.login(data);"

The guilty code :

```
angular.module("SessionManager", ['http-auth-interceptor','restangular'])
        .constant('constSessionExpiry', 20) // in minutes
        .factory("$Session", [
                '$rootScope',
                '$q',
                '$location',
                '$log',
                '$http',
                'constSessionExpiry',


                function($rootScope, $q, $location, $log, $http, Restangular, authService, constSessionExpiry) {
                    return {
                        login: function(data){
                                $log.info("Preparing Login Data", data);
                                var $this = this;
                                return Restangular
                                    .setBaseUrl('backend/api/v1')
                                    .all('user/login/')
                                    .post(data)
                                    .then(function userLoginSuccess(response){
                                            $log.info("login.post: auth-success", response);
                                            $this.User = response;
                                            // remove properties we don't need.
                                            delete $this.User.route;
                                            delete $this.User.restangularCollection;
                                            $this.User.is_authenticated = true;
                                            $this.cacheUser();
                                            $this.setApiKeyAuthHeader();
                                            $this.authSuccess();
                                        }, function userLoginFailed(response){
                                            $log.info('login.post: auth-failed', response);
                                            $this.logout();
                                            return $q.reject(response);
                                        });
                        },
                    };
                }])
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: It's hard to tell where these errors are when the line numbers in the error don't seem to match the javascript file. Would you confirm what lines 110 and 207 of session.js say?

Comment: You're right, I did a modification since the error paste, sorry.
The bad line at 110 is : ".setBaseUrl('backend/api/v1')"
And the 207 is :"$Session.login(data);"
Thanks

Comment: The error means that `$Session` is undefined at [L221](https://github.com/Seraf/LISA-WEB-Frontend/blob/e25f969f0f6e9eef0b8269cb6d30ce11489855f7/src/common/factories/session.js#L221), at this point I can't be much help since I've never used the angular library, but it looks like when `function($rootScope, $log, $Session, $state){` is called, that it is not receiving a $Session parameter. [L208](https://github.com/Seraf/LISA-WEB-Frontend/blob/e25f969f0f6e9eef0b8269cb6d30ce11489855f7/src/common/factories/session.js#L208)

Comment: [Looking into the restangular library for setBaseUrl](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/search?q=setBaseURL&ref=cmdform) it doesn't look like they use it the same way. Is that related? It looks like you need to use a [configurer](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#configuring-restangular) first

Comment: According to https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/blob/9b875897ae0e4a32f5474fed459ae9ad51f48092/README.md#properties I can use this function with Restangular directly.
I tried to log.info() my $Session object, and it contains all functions defined in my factory. But trying the same thing with Restangular returns me "20" and not an object with functions...
Don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your dependency injection wrong:

```
.factory("$Session", [
         '$rootScope','$q','$location','$log','$http','constSessionExpiry',
 function($rootScope, $q, $location, $log, $http, Restangular, authService, constSessionExpiry) {
```

You're injecting `constSessionExpiry` as `Restangular` and nothing for the latter two services.

This means that calling `Restangular.setBaseUrl` is actually looking for `20.setBaseUrl` which is undefined and not a function -- hence the error!

To get on the road to a fix, make sure you're passing the right service names to match your function arguments, e.g.:

```
.factory("$Session", [
         '$rootScope','$q','$location','$log','$http','Restangular','authService','constSessionExpiry',
 function($rootScope, $q, $location, $log, $http, Restangular, authService, constSessionExpiry) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem. I didn't understood that dependencies order have an effect on function arguments. Sorry, I need to read more documentation about angularjs.